# pthread_cond_broadcast without busy wait in POSIX

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I am new to multithreading and stuck with a segmentation fault. I am using

```
void addfunction(void *xyz)
{
    flag_TO_go = 1;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&check_Queue2);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&get_mutex);
}

void delete_thread(void *abc)
{
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&get_mutex);
        while (!flag_TO_go ) {//condition variable
            pthread_cond_wait(&check, &get_mutex);
        }
        flag_To_go= 1;
        //things to do
        //delete elemenst from a linked list
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&get_mutex);
    }
}
```

What i am getting is a segmentation fault because My list does not have any element after first element deletion. but my thread is aqcquiring lock  and checking it
 Is there any other way to use cond wait .

If any one can suggest a way to do this without busy wait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
void addfunction(void *xyz)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&get_mutex);
    flag_TO_go = 1;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&check_Queue2);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&get_mutex);
}

void delete_thread(void *abc)
{
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&get_mutex);
        while (!flag_TO_go ) {//condition variable
            pthread_cond_wait(&check, &get_mutex);
        }
        flag_To_go= 0;
        //things to do
        //delete elemenst from a linked list
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&get_mutex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to lock the mutex before setting `flag_TO_go = 1` in `addfunction`.

And if things to do really means taking items off of a list perhaps you should be checking for a not-empty list instead of using a flag_TO_go variable.

Also, you set the flag to 1 in both functions which I do not understand the point of. Are you sure that is right?

Comment: Yes , I initialised flag_To_go to 0 globally so whenever signal comes. Delete function will acquire the lock and performs the delete. I am putting mutex lock before setting flag to 1.
is there any other way to use cond wait

Comment: @user2825892: Yes, setting it globally to 0 happens one time. Where does it get set to 0 after being set to 1?

Comment: I am not changing it to 0 . because once my list get appended with all elements my thread(addfucntion) exits and deletefunction(thread) has to delete the elements untill empty. SO here the situation is if i make flag_to_go = 0 after one operation it will not check list again (and signaling thread is dead now) and if i make it 1. it start checking for elements before they get appended.